# when replicaset is 1 then what are 1/2 pods for prometheus server?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Using helm chart :

```
helm install monitor prometheus-community/prometheus -n monitoring -f ./values.yaml
```

I cannot get prometheus server to running.

```
# kubectl get pods -owide -n monitoring
NAME                                              READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE   IP               NODE              NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
monitor-kube-state-metrics-578cdbb5b7-ffnbc       0/1     Running            0          19s   192.168.23.10    kube-worker-vm3   <none>           <none>
monitor-prometheus-alertmanager-c94f7b6b7-znfp5   1/2     Running            0          19s   192.168.222.53   kube-worker-vm2   <none>           <none>
monitor-prometheus-node-exporter-5vksg            1/1     Running            0          20s   192.168.1.36     kube-worker-vm2   <none>           <none>
monitor-prometheus-pushgateway-8694884546-qgqd2   0/1     Running            0          19s   192.168.222.54   kube-worker-vm2   <none>           <none>
monitor-prometheus-server-5587c7f464-z9tcj        1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   1          19s   192.168.222.55   kube-worker-vm2   <none>           <none>
```

Even though I had 1 replicaSet out of 2 running or crashloopbakcoff.

```
# kubectl describe pod monitor-prometheus-server-5587c7f464-z9tcj -n monitoring
Name:         monitor-prometheus-server-5587c7f464-z9tcj
Namespace:    monitoring
Priority:     0
Node:         kube-worker-vm2/192.168.1.36
Start Time:   Sun, 09 May 2021 22:14:12 +0100
Labels:       app=prometheus
              chart=prometheus-13.8.0
              component=server
              heritage=Helm
              pod-template-hash=5587c7f464
              release=monitor
Annotations:  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 192.168.222.55/32
              cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 192.168.222.55/32
Status:       Running
IP:           192.168.222.55
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.222.55
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/monitor-prometheus-server-5587c7f464
Containers:
  prometheus-server-configmap-reload:
    Container ID:  docker://d4fdd420ec67f42857a4f20dd56de146307c65c49cd8ffccf6153f0b54082e91
    Image:         jimmidyson/configmap-reload:v0.4.0
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://jimmidyson/configmap-reload@sha256:17d34fd73f9e8a78ba7da269d96822ce8972391c2838e08d92a990136adb8e4a
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Args:
      --volume-dir=/etc/config
      --webhook-url=http://127.0.0.1:9090/-/reload
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sun, 09 May 2021 22:14:19 +0100
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/config from config-volume (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from monitor-prometheus-server-token-njbp9 (ro)
  prometheus-server:
    Container ID:  docker://b53d3a56e2985594046a3b0018e9828597678268119c2dd7b07b1c7b315246e3
    Image:         prom/prometheus:v2.20.1
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://prom/prometheus@sha256:788260ebd13613456c168d2eed8290f119f2b6301af2507ff65908d979c66c17
    Port:          9090/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Args:
      --storage.tsdb.retention.time=15d
      --config.file=/etc/config/prometheus.yml
      --storage.tsdb.path=/data
      --web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries
      --web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles
      --web.enable-lifecycle
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    2
      Started:      Sun, 09 May 2021 22:20:24 +0100
      Finished:     Sun, 09 May 2021 22:20:24 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  6
    Liveness:       http-get http://:9090/-/healthy delay=30s timeout=30s period=15s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:9090/-/ready delay=30s timeout=30s period=5s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /data from storage-volume (rw)
      /etc/config from config-volume (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from monitor-prometheus-server-token-njbp9 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  config-volume:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      monitor-prometheus-server
    Optional:  false
  storage-volume:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  prometheus-pv-claim
    ReadOnly:   false
  monitor-prometheus-server-token-njbp9:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  monitor-prometheus-server-token-njbp9
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  boardType=x86vm
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                     From               Message
  ----     ------       ----                    ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    9m19s                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned monitoring/monitor-prometheus-server-5587c7f464-z9tcj to kube-worker-vm2
  Warning  FailedMount  9m18s                   kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "config-volume" : failed to sync configmap cache: timed out waiting for the condition
  Normal   Pulled       9m13s                   kubelet            Container image "jimmidyson/configmap-reload:v0.4.0" already present on machine
  Normal   Created      9m13s                   kubelet            Created container prometheus-server-configmap-reload
  Normal   Started      9m12s                   kubelet            Started container prometheus-server-configmap-reload
  Normal   Pulled       8m24s (x4 over 9m12s)   kubelet            Container image "prom/prometheus:v2.20.1" already present on machine
  Normal   Created      8m23s (x4 over 9m12s)   kubelet            Created container prometheus-server
  Normal   Started      8m22s (x4 over 9m12s)   kubelet            Started container prometheus-server
  Warning  BackOff      4m16s (x32 over 9m10s)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `monitor-prometheus-server-5587c7f464-z9tcj        1/2     CrashLoopBackOff`

`1/2` here means that 1 of 2 **containers** in the Pod is "Ready"

When you describe the Pod, you see the status of the containers:

```
Containers:
  prometheus-server-configmap-reload:
    Ready:          True
...
  prometheus-server:
    Ready:          False
```

You probably need to check the logs for the crashing container to see the reason.